# What does an Apache Curator "connection string" look like?

Tags: apache-curator

How does the connection string given to `CuratorFrameworkFactory#newClient` look like? So far I haven't found any information on the web and the JavaDoc doesn't tell me the correct format.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27748170/260805), it is of the format

```
IP1:PORT1,IP2:PORT2,...,IPn:PORTn
```

. For example:

```
127.0.0.1:2181,127.0.0.1:2182,127.0.0.1:2183,127.0.0.1:2184
```

Comment: One of the worst instances of "everything is documented, but the documentation tells you nothing" I've seen in a public API. I kept following the source through various builder methods and eventually until I got to FixedEnsembleProvider and gave up, no dice. It's just "the connection string" in every Javadoc all the way down.

Answer (score 3):

Curator is an API client for Apache Zookeeper so the full documented answer to this is available in the Zookeeper Javadocs:
[Zookeeper Javadocs](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.2.2/api/org/apache/zookeeper/ZooKeeper.html#ZooKeeper(java.lang.String,%20int,%20org.apache.zookeeper.Watcher))

> connectString - comma separated host:port pairs, each corresponding to a zk server. e.g. "127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:3001,127.0.0.1:3002" If the optional chroot suffix is used the example would look like: "127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:3001,127.0.0.1:3002/app/a" where the client would be rooted at "/app/a" and all paths would be relative to this root - ie getting/setting/etc... "/foo/bar"